# Failing to load CSV data through Omnivore

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to load a CSV file, convert it to GeoJSON, add an empty geoJson layer and then adding data to that geoJson layer. Why is it not working?

```
var locations = 'locations.csv';

var x = omnivore.csv(locations);

var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
geojsonLayer.addData(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`omnivore.csv`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#api) returns a layer built with the loaded data, not the underlying GeoJSON object.

Try

```
var geojsonLayer = omnivore.csv(locations);
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

Or build your layer and pass it to `omnivore.csv`:

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
omnivore.csv('locations.csv', null, geojsonLayer);
```

Or ditch omnivore and use [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson)  to load your data before populating your layer :

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    csv2geojson.csv2geojson(this.responseText, {}, function(err, data) {
        geojsonLayer.addData(data);
    });
};
xhr.open('GET', 'locations.csv', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: This works. But I wanted to create an empty GeoJson layer and then add my csv data to it. How do i do that? I was using omnivore to convert my data into GeoJson.

Comment: Then don't use omnivore, use its CSV module, [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson)

Comment: Or pass a custom layer to `omnivore.csv`

Comment: I've added an example for both solutions.